# Анимировать View с помощью two-way data DataBinding

Tags: java, android, android-data-binding

Я использую паттерн MVVM
В XML у меня есть View, которое нужно анимировать в зависимости от изменения ViewModel 
Есть ли у кого-нибудь примеры?
P.S С изменением параметров таких как текст, цвета кнопки, и т.д проблем нет, но как вызывать анимацию у View не понятно,используя DataBinding

Пробовал создавать свой BindingAdapter, с interface, но анимация проигрывалась один раз.

Comment: меня смутило " анимация проигрывалась один раз". Анимация всегда приогрывается 1 раз, без сохранения конечного состояния. Затем ее нужно перезапустить. Мб у вас проблема непосредственно с самой анимацией, а не организацией воспроизведения анимации?

Comment: Блин, точно, спасибо.
Не перезапускал анимацию.